# Angular {{code}} is visible during rotating mobile device

Tags: angularjs, mobile, responsive-design

I have responsive angular web-site. When i use it on mobile device i can see different angular code strings eq.

"{{some.objects.value}}"

when rotation is over value seems to be ok.Any sugestions to hide angular code on rotation?

Comment: you could use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). This will hide sections of the page until the angular elements have rendered. This happens on rotation because the page is being re-rendered, so you briefly see the uncompiled angular strings.

Add this to your css

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Then you can use the `ng-cloak` dirrective on any element.

```
<div id="item" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Comment: Also we can use ng-bind instead of {{}} which will be helpful